# Ajax returning multiple output?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object, xmlhttprequest

I simple want to get data from product.json file.
in which i have store two object

1. (1) object for CCTV camera products
   2.(2)object for Laptop products.

I want to get data of LAPTOP products when particular button click and same for CCTV.

**But problem is AJAX returning both the objects at the same time i also apply condition .i just want to get one object at a time**

```
    //for fetching CCtv camera products                                                                                             
    const fetchdata = document.getElementById("fetchNetworkProducts");
    fetchdata.onclick = fetchproducts("CCTV");
    //for fetching laptop products
    const fetchLaptopData = document.getElementById("fetchlaptop");
    fetchLaptopData.onclick = fetchproducts("Laptop");

function fetchproducts(product) {//identifying which click event occur
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("get", "/jsondata/Products.json", true);
  xhr.onload = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log();
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    if (this.status === 200) {
      if (product === "CCTV") {
        fillProducts(obj.CCTV);
      } else if (product === "Laptop") {
        fillProducts(obj.Laptop);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("some_error_occur");
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you called your function i.e :`fetchproducts("Laptop");` the value return from the function gets assign to `fetchLaptopData.onclick` and this get automatically called as you can see in below demo code :

```js
//for fetching CCtv camera products                                                                                             
const fetchdata = document.getElementById("fetchNetworkProducts");
fetchdata.onclick = fetchproducts("CCTV");
//for fetching laptop products
const fetchLaptopData = document.getElementById("fetchlaptop");
fetchLaptopData.onclick = fetchproducts("Laptop");

function fetchproducts(product) { //identifying which click event occur
  console.log(product);
  //your ajax code..

}
```

```html
<button id="fetchNetworkProducts">Abc</button>
<button id="fetchlaptop">Abc</button>
```

Instead call your **function** like below :

```js
//for fetching CCtv camera products                                                                                         
document.getElementById('fetchNetworkProducts').onclick = function() { //call function
  fetchproducts('CCTV');
}

document.getElementById('fetchlaptop').onclick = function() {
  fetchproducts('Laptop');
}

function fetchproducts(product) { //identifying which click event occur
  console.log(product);
 //your ajax code..

}
```

```html
<button id="fetchNetworkProducts">Abc</button>
<button id="fetchlaptop">Abc</button>
```

Comment: preventDefault stop working after this.?kindly also guide me about thus

Comment: You don't need that here  please remove and see if that work or not.Also I suggest you read about it why we use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: I want to show my products only one time.duplicates products are adding.mean every time i click same products from json calling

Comment: you need to empty div where data are display and then add new data in it